# If the 'id' key is duplicated among the objects in the array, how to delete the object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, duplicates

If the 'id' key is duplicated among the objects in the array, how to delete the object

I tried using filter, map, and set, but it doesn't work.
It's not a one-dimensional array, so I don't know how to do it.

as-is

```
"category": {
    "key": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "12345",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "67890",
            ...
        },
        
    ]
}
```

to-be

```
"category": {
    "key": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "67890",
            ...
        },
        
    ]
}
```

Comment: `obj.category.list = obj.category.list.filter((o,i,a) => a.findIndex(o2 => o2.id == o.id) == i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We iterate over that list using `reduce` function, then we checked whether the key we are accessing is visited or not with `keys` parameter of `reduce` method, and if it's not visited then we just push that object to a filtered array and returning keys array to keep it updated.

```js
const data = {
  "category": {
    "key": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "list": [{
        "id": "12345"
      },
      {
        "id": "12345"
      },
      {
        "id": "67890"
      },

    ]
  }
}
let filtered = [];

data.category.list.reduce((keys, currentObject) => {
  if (!keys.includes(currentObject.id)) { //checking if current oject id is present in keys or not
    // if not present than we will just push that object in 
    keys.push(currentObject.id);
    //getting filttered object
    filtered.push(currentObject);
  }
  return keys; //returning keys to update it
}, [])
data.category.list = filtered; //updating list
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on @Nick's comment

```js
let data ={
"category": {
    "key": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "12345"
        },
        {
            "id": "12345"
        },
        {
            "id": "67890"
        },
        
    ]
}
}


let uniq = data.category.list.filter((o,i,a) => a.findIndex(o2 => o2.id == o.id) == i)
data.category.list = uniq
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to track if id

```js
const category = [{
  "category": {
    "key": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "list": [{
        "id": "12345",
      },
      {
        "id": "12345",
      },
      {
        "id": "67890",
      },

    ]
  }
}]
const z = category.map(elem => {
  const set = new Set()
  return {
    ...elem,
    category: {
      ...elem.category,
      list: elem.category.list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if (!set.has(curr.id)) {
          set.add(curr.id);
          acc.push(curr)
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])
    }
  }
});
console.log(z)
```